# Angular Reactive forms formgroup

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I need to have a formControl for two different arrays under the same node so I could add and delete a respective nested node in the given Reactive form.

Expected JSON Format:

```
{
  "title": null,
  "days": [
    {
      "date": null,
      "nodes": [
        {
          "type": "leg",
          "from": null,
          "to": null
        },
        {
          "type": "activity",
          "category": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have implemented control on day and node for which I was able to add and delete the form fields respectively however I need separate controls for type leg and activity under nodes.

Is there any way to implement nested formControl in here?

Update:
Need two formgroups under a form array, please help to implement in HTML.

```
initX() {
    return this.fb.group({
      'date': [],
      'nodes': this.fb.array([
        this.initY(),
        this.initZ()
      ]),
    });
  }

  initY() {
    return this.fb.group({
      'type': ['leg'],
      'from': [],
      'to': []
    })
  }

  initZ() {
    return this.fb.group({
      'type': ['activity'],
      'category':[],
      'cost':[]
    })
  }
```

Error: Cannot find control with path: 'days -> 0 -> nodes -> 1 -> from'

Can find the stackblitz of the sample code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fkgxrr

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "I need separate controls for type leg and activity under nodes", because in your sample you already have two different methods with different structures returned.

Comment: Hi @FrancescoColamonici I was able to format in the JSON however not have any controls in the formArray under HTML. The days and nodes are looped individually with seperate controls, I want the same to be done for Leg and Activities however under nodes.

Comment: @FrancescoColamonici I have updated my description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, in my another answer, the "nodes" array is like

```
[
 {"type": "leg","from": null,"to": null,"category": null}
 {"type": "leg","from": null,"to": null,"category": null}
]
```

A formArray need has all his elements with the sames properties

**Question**: nodes is only an array with two elements (one for control Leg and another one for control category)?

In this case days is a formArray, each element is a formGroup with two peoperies, one of them is **an array** (not a formArray) with two elements

```
form=new FormGroup({
  title:new FormControl()
  days:new FormArray([
     date:new FormControl(),
     nodes:[new FormGroup({...}),new FormGroup({..})]
  ])
})
```

in this case you can has three getter

```
get days():FormArray
{
    return this.formGroup.get('days') as FormArray;
}
get leg(index)
{
    return this.days.at(i).get('nodes')[0] as FormGroup
}
get category(index)
{
    return this.days.at(i).get('nodes')[1] as FormGroup
}
```

And use directly `[formGroup]` in a div, e.g.

```
<div [formGroup]="category[i]">
   <input formControlName="from">
   ...
</div>
```

else I can not understand your json

Answer (score 0):

Try using two way data binding. This will simplify your process.

Eg:

```
<input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="model.name">
```

Answer (score 0):

keethama, step by step. You has a formArray inside a formArray, so make two functions that return a formArray

```
  get days():FormArray
  {
    return this.formGroup.get('days') as FormArray;
  }
  getNodes(i:number):FormArray
  {
    return this.days.at(i).get('nodes') as FormArray
  }
```

Well, to create the form divide and use three functions:

```
  createForm(data:any)
  {
    data=data || {title:null,days:null}
    return new FormGroup({
      title:new FormControl(data.title),
      days:data.days?
           new FormArray(data.days.map(d=>this.createDays(d))):
           new FormArray([])
      
    })
  }
  createDays(data:any=null)
  {
    data=data || {date:null,nodes:null}
    return new FormGroup({
        date:new FormControl(data.date),
        nodes:data.nodes?
              new FormArray(data.nodes.map(x=>this.createNodes(x))):
              new FormArray([])
    })
  }
  createNodes(data:any=null)
  {
    data={type:null,from:null,to:null,category:null,...data}
    return new FormGroup({
      type: new FormControl(data.type),
      from: new FormControl(data.from),
      to: new FormControl(data.to),
      category: new FormControl(data.category)
    })
  }
```

Well, now take a look to the .html

```
<form *ngIf="formGroup" [formGroup]="formGroup">
  title:<input formControlName="title">
  <div formArrayName="days">
    <div *ngFor="let groupDays of days.controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
        date:<input formControlName="date">
        <div formArrayName="nodes">
          <div *ngFor="let groupnodes of getNodes(i).controls;let j=index" [formGroupName]="j">        
            type:<input formControlName="type"><br/>
        from:<input formControlName="from"><br/>

        to:<input formControlName="to"><br/>
        category:<input formControlName="category">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And in ngOnInit

```
this.formGroup=this.createForm(this.data)
```

See that if you want to add a new node to the node in index index you use

```
   this.getNodes(index).push(this.createNodes())
```

And to add a new node to the days array

```
   this.days.push(this.createDays())
```

An [incomplete stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejevkd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the sample code, however the code here still have the same formArray and controls for all nodes. I need controls for Leg and Activity separately under nodes. Is there any possible suggestion?

Comment: nodes is only an array with two elements (one for control Leg and another one for control category)? If true, see my another answer, else I can not understand your json.

Answer (score 0):

I see it might not be a full response, because a working sample with nested FormArrays would take some time, but I'm pretty sure you will find interesting and helpful this article (that helped me out in a lot of situations like this):

- https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a